# Swallowing an exception when extending Thread

Tags: java, concurrency

Chapter 5 in JCIP -

> The only situation in which it is acceptable to swallow an interrupt
>   is when you are extending Thread and **therefore control all the code
>   higher up on the call stack**.

Please elaborate the part in bold. How?

Comment: What you swallow? any Exception or InterruptedException?

Answer (score 0):

On Java each thread has its own stack and a method is called a new frame is added.

You can create your own threads by extending Thread class:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("MyThread");

        // Interruption 1 
    }
}
```

And thread stack is:

| Stack         |
| --------------|
| run           |

Or if you write a library, an external thread that is not created by you calls your library:

```
class MyLib {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("MyThread");

        // Interruption 2
    }
}
```

Within an external thread:

```
...
MyLib myLib = new MyLib();
myLib.doSomething();
...
```

your code is called like above.

In this case

| Stack             |
| ------------------|
| some other method |
| some other method |
| some other method |
| doSomething       |

And you do not have direct control on code that calling your code. `some other method`s are higher up on call stack.

So swallowing Interruption 1 is OK but Interruption 2 is not.